# How to show Gif image in Glide on Android

Tags: android, android-glide

I want show **Gif** image in `Glide` library. I write below codes but when show my gif, show very very **slow motion** . i want show gif normally bit rate not slow motion.

```
ImageView test = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.testImageGif);
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(test);
Glide.with(this)
        .load(R.drawable.login_image)
        .into(imageViewTarget);
```

how can it?

Comment: follow this link, this might help you [visit here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082330/show-gif-file-with-glide-image-loading-and-caching-library)

Comment: try to use *.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)*  `..// .load(R.drawable.login_image) .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE) //.....` and see

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ImageView test = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.testImageGif);
    Glide  
    .with(this)
    .load(R.drawable.login_image)
    .asGif()
    .into(test);
```

Comment: I use this code, but not work me and not show any gif image!

Answer (score 0):

as @SachinThampan said [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082330/show-gif-file-with-glide-image-loading-and-caching-library#:%7E:text=55-,For%20Glide%204.%2B,-ImageView%20imageView%20%3D%20)

Xml:

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/title_gif"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/gif_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/gif_height"
                />
```

Java:

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.title_gif);
    Glide.with(this).asGif().load(R.raw.animated_gif).into(imageView);
```

In build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
```