# Glide error() request option stop working after adding thumbnail()

Tags: android, android-glide

Now i was working on an demo app that load movies data from an api and i figured out that Glide is a bet faster than Picasso so after using it and adding

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.error(R.drawable.poster_placeholder);

Glide.with(context)
     .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
     .load(film.getPoster())into(poster);
```

error() works fine
but i need to add loading gif to improve UX 
so i find this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39947110/5464294) to add gif and it works great but error() stop working, gif is always run now.

the new code is

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.error(R.drawable.poster_placeholder);

Glide.with(context)
     .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
     .load(film.getPoster())
     .thumbnail(Glide.with(context)
     .load(R.drawable.placeholdergif)).into(poster);
```

i need a solution that make error() works again
or other way to display loading image til the image is loaded.

Comment: Use `.apply(requestOptions)` instead of `.setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)` like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44943830/7666442

Comment: nothing is changed @NileshRathod

Answer (score 0):

This is super simple now with the `CircularProgressDrawable` released in 26.1.0 (Support library):

```
  CircularProgressDrawable circularProgressDrawable = 
  CircularProgressDrawable(this);
  circularProgressDrawable.strokeWidth = 5f;
  circularProgressDrawable.centerRadius = 30f;
  circularProgressDrawable.start();

  Glide.with(context)
  .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
  .load(film.getPoster())
  .thumbnail(Glide.with(context)
  .placeholder(circularProgressDrawable)
  .into(a_main_image);
}
```